# Orthophoto processed with Photoscan distorted in QGis

Tags: qgis, orthophoto

I processed an orthophotomosaic via Photoscan using geotagged images in EPSG 4326 and it is displayed correctly in Photoscan and GoogleEarth. When I put it in QGis it is distorted. The coordinate system in QGis is set correctly.

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: I can see in your screenshot that the project CRS is 4326. What CRS is set in the layer properties?

Comment: The layer properties´ CRS is also 4326